# Importing react components from private npm repo

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and have been trying to find my way through. I have created a react component and published it to a private npm repo. so the component is accessed as `@myorg/testcomponent`.

I did an `npm install --save @myorg/testcomponent` to install the component into a project created via `create-react-app`

Inside react, when I do the following, the import fails

```
import TestComponent from '@myorg/testcomponent'
```

gives:

```
Failed to compile.
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@myorg/testcomponent' in '/mnt/c/Workspaces/ui/test_project/src'
```

I am not sure why it is trying to resolve it from the `src` directory, while the component is installed in `node_modules`

how do I get it to resolve from `node_modules`, is there some step i am missing?

Comment: you installed it from that location, but what name did it have in the associated `package.json`? Because that'll be the name you want to use.

Comment: In `package.json` its `@myorg/testcomponent`

Comment: What was the log result from `npm install --save @myorg/testcomponent`?

Comment: It installed successfully and is saved in my projects node_modules.

Note: @myorg is a substitution for the actual organization name i am using

I am guessing, because the `import` statement contains a path like `<scope>/<packagename>` it is trying to resolve the module inside the src folder

Comment: it should only do that if there is no leading `@`. As `@scope/thing` it should resolve to the node_modules scoped dir, not the local dir. Which version of node/npm?

Comment: Thanks for the comments Mike, 
`Node Version : 8.9.4`
`Npm Version : 6.1.0`

I wasnt able to get this to work. so i ended up using and install from the git privaterepo directly

`npm install --save https:/oauth2:<token>@gitlab.com/orgname/testcomponent`

Comment: it might be worth filing on the npm issue tracker though (at the very least they would be able to explain what you did wrong better than anyone else, if it's not a bug)